# Not able to sent email in localhost server

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail

Sorry for this question again. I want to send email in PHP for that i used simple mail() function. Using sendmail.exe. Change the php.ini fie like

```
SMTP = localhost (tried both comment and uncomment this)
smtp_port = 25 tried(587)
sendmail_path = "D:\sendmail\sendmail.exe"
```

in my sendmailpth.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
default_domain=localhost
auth_username=mygmaill@gmail.com
auth_password=*********
force_sender=mygmail@gmail.com
hostname=localhost
```

my email.php code:

```
<?php
//ini_set('localhost');
$to = "sommai@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: mygmail@gmail.com";

if(mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers)){ 
    echo "message sent";
} else {
    echo "mail sent fail";
}
?>
```

it shows mail send in echo but never receive any mail.

Please guide me solve this.

Comment: Did you check your spam

Comment: @Anu check your spam folder

Comment: @Uchiha yes checked but not yet received....

Comment: did you check the logs written by sendmail.exe?

Comment: @Paolo it shows shows like `connection closed gracefully`

Comment: @Anu connection closed gracefully does not mean 'connection closed gracefully after successfully sending the email message'. if possible raise the detail of the log.

Comment: @Paolo this is only i have in error.log

Comment: @Paolo need to configure server details ah?

Comment: @Anu you have to tell sendmail 'please sendmail record as much information as possible while sending the email'. there should be some parameter for that, check the documentation of that software.

Comment: @Paolo yes do the same..

Comment: @Paolo exactly same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879322/sending-an-email-using-wamp-and-sendmail?rq=1